Pinescript two horizontal lines, prevent auto adjusting
I am trying to draw two horizontal line in pine script that are triggered based on certain conditions. I want the lines to go horizontally to the right until the conditions are met again and then have the lines redraw at the new point. But all I can see to figure out how to do it have them plot and then they adjust to the next time the condition is met.In the image white is what the code is doing and the red lines are what I need it to do. Any help is greatly appreciated.
indicator("Zones Test", overlay=true)

box_high = high[1]
box_low = low
testCondition1 = false


if low[1] < low[2] and high > high[1]
    if close[1] > open[1] and close[0] < open[0]
        testCondition1 := true
        box_high := high
        box_low := low[1]
        




plot(testCondition1 ? box_high : na, color=color.white, title="First Minute High", linewidth = 1)
plot(testCondition1 ? box_low : na, color=color.white, title="First Minute Low", linewidth = 1)


I have tried hline but it wont take a series, I don't need a series I just need the values at the time the condition is met.
